# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Anime & Manga Stack Exchange](http://anime.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is Misa Amane's early death a plothole in Death Note?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11296/is-misa-amanes-early-death-a-plothole-in-death-note)

**Net Score: 30** (Excellent: 30, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Manga about WWII in Japan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11264/manga-about-wwii-in-japan)

**Net Score: 17** (Excellent: 19, Satisfactory: 17, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How much of the manga plot does the anime of Aku no Hana cover?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11406/how-much-of-the-manga-plot-does-the-anime-cover)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 16, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [What makes the mannequins different from the results of the sacrifices' human transmutation attempts?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/12783/what-makes-the-mannequins-different-from-the-results-of-the-sacrifices-human-tr)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 18, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Does the prime minister die at the end?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11261/does-the-prime-minister-die-at-the-end)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 22, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11279/girl-in-a-very-short-white-skirt-what-anime-is-this

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 19, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

- [Are there any anime series with neither an opening or ending song?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11647/are-there-any-anime-series-with-neither-an-opening-or-ending-song)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 9)

---

- [Why can't Earthland magicians use magic in Edolas without the X-balls?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11295/why-cant-earthland-magicians-use-magic-in-edolas-without-the-x-balls)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 19, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

- [What's up with the Black Butler intermissions?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11719/whats-up-with-the-black-butler-intermissions)

**Net Score: -9** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 17, Needs Improvement: 12)

---

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/searching-for-a-certain-yaoi-manga-about-a-guy-who-takes-in-a-boy

**Net Score: -28** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 29)

---

Comment: Not that downvotes matter... but I'm curious as to what your scoring system is. Are we doing this by upvotes vs downvotes... or total upvotes vs your suggested 'quality' of the answer? So much confusion... honestly it only makes sense to downvote (but I haven't). Please clarify :) In retrospect, I see you've accepted your own answer. Not that it matters, but... really? Community man, that's your username! While I would say that maybe *too many* questions on this SE site (and others) are subject to "what is this thing that I'm thinking of?" I think there needs to be a more critical evaluation.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice The user 'Community' is a bot/robot. It isn't actually a real person in retrospect.

Comment: I was being sarcastic. Well, trying to be. I know that community is a bot - I was hoping that since nobody provided any actual feedback, that somebody would based on my comment. +9 vote on the question and -2 on the only answer demonstrates that more discussion needs to be done concerning this question/answer.